# Using tryInvoke when controller actions are wrapped

Tags: ember.js

Newest guidelines state to wrap controller actions inside a

```
actions: {
  loadMore: function() {}
}
```

When I do so the code I previously had to fire an action on a controller no longer works:

```
Ember.tryInvoke(view.get('controller'), 'loadMore');
```

What would be the proper way to get this going again?

### Edit

The complete code that uses the tryInvoke:

```
  didInsertElement: function() {
    'use strict';

    var view = this;
    this.$().bind('inview', function(event, isInView, visiblePartX, visiblePartY) {
      if (isInView) {
        Ember.tryInvoke(view.get('controller'), 'loadMore');
      }
    });
  },
```

Comment: What is the view action that triggers `Ember.tryInvoke(view.get('controller'), 'loadMore');`, click, mouseup ... ?

Comment: @MárcioRodriguesCorreaJúnior I just added the code

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Ember.ViewTargetActionSupport](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ViewTargetActionSupport.html), and set the `action` property to the action name that you want, in that case `loadMore`. Using `triggerAction` will send the action.

Because the jquery event is detached from ember run loop I wrapped the triggerAction in Ember.run.

```
App.YourView = Ember.View.extend(Ember.ViewTargetActionSupport, {
  action: 'loadMore',
  didInsertElement: function() {
    'use strict';

    var view = this;
    this.$().bind('inview', function(event, isInView, visiblePartX, visiblePartY) {
      if (isInView) {
        Ember.run(function() {
          view.triggerAction();
        });        
      }
    });
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're getting the controller right?  According to a commit a couple months ago in Ember 1.2, the controller is now accessible from a view as "targetObject" rather than "controller":

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/326af5a9c88df76f5effe11156a07b64c8b178a3#packages/ember-handlebars/lib/controls/text_support.js

Comment: I'm on 1.0, there it's still the `view.get('controller')`